# Oracle query can't return a row even if the parameter should return a row

Tags: oracle

I have a tmp_table with a field receiving_institution(varchar2) . I will not provide the other fields to make this simple.

```
    receiving_institution|
    ----------------------
    19
    26
    50
    etc.

    select * from tmp_table where receiving_institution = '19' -> returns 0 row(unexpected result)
    select * from tmp_table where receiving_institution like '%19%' -> returns row(expected result)
```

The second query's result return receiving_institution '19' (no spaces).
When I edit manually the '19' to '19' by typing it, after that the first query works. I think it's on the data itself. By the way I test it also on the main table (autho_activity) and it's the same result.

Comment: You need to show the EXACT table schema definition, and the sample data in it.  It is not going to be an oracle bug.

Comment: Perhaps there's more than just '19', e.g. other nonprintable characters.

Comment: Use TRIM(receiving_institution)='19' in your query. If you get rows after making this change then you have either leading or trailing spaces in your receiving_institution values.

Comment: This will be an artefact of your data and not an Oracle bug.  You can post it here if you like but basically you just need to investigate it more closely.

Comment: Of course, the way your system abuses the table will make you investigations harder. Perhaps you really need a proper temporary table?  Check out [Global Temporary Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1138)